# Switch from file contents to STDIN in piped command? (Linux Shell)

Tags: bash, file, shell, named-pipes, pipe

I have a program (that I did not write) which is not designed to read in commands from a file. Entering commands on STDIN is pretty tedious, so I'd like to be able to automate it by writing the commands in a file for re-use. Trouble is, if the program hits EOF, it loops infinitely trying to read in the next command dropping an endless torrent of menu options on the screen.

What I'd like to be able to do is cat a file containing the commands into the program via a pipe, then use some sort of shell magic to have it switch from the file to STDIN when it hits the file's EOF.

Note: I've already considered using cat with the '-' for STDIN. Unfortunately (I didn't know this before), piped commands wait for the first program's output to terminate before starting the second program -- they do not run in parallel. If there's some way to get the programs to run in parallel with that kind of piping action, that would work!

Any thoughts? Thanks for any assistance!

EDIT:

I should note that my goal is not only to prevent the system from hitting the end of the commands file. I would like to be able to continue typing in commands from the keyboard when the file hits EOF.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would do something like

```
(cat your_file_with_commands; cat) | sh your_script
```

That way, when the file with commands is done, the second `cat` will feed your script with whatever you type on stdin afterwards.

Comment: You can *do that?* I had no idea you could group commands. That's my something new for the day. This keeps me from having to use a second window -- thanks greatly, Idelic!

Comment: For those who are interested, you can build onto the file containing commands as you go by using:               (cat your_file_with_commands; tee -a your_file_with_commands) | sh your_script                    which will append each command to the file in addition to passing it to the script via the pipe.

Answer (score 3):

Same as Idelic answer with more simple syntax ;)

```
cat your_file_with_commands - | sh your_script
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think `expect` would work for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using something like `tail -f commandfile | command`  I think that should pipe the lines of the file to command without closing the file descriptor afterwards.  Use `-n` to specify the number of lines to be piped if `tail -f` doesn't catch all of them.

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately doesn't let me continue to type in commands after the file has been completed. (I should have been clearer on that in my posting -- I'll edit it.) If you type 'tail -f commandfile -' to try and have it switch to STDIN after reading the file, it complains: 

warning: following standard input indefinitely is ineffective

Thanks for the thought, though!

Comment: Have you tried appending lines to the file using `echo something >> commandfile`?  `tail -f` should track those additions too.

Comment: Ha! I was *just* trying that. I'll comment again if it works. (The program takes a while to get going.)

Comment: Success! I have one window running 'tail -n $NUM_LINES_IN_FILE -f $FILENAME | $PROGRAM_NAME' and another running 'cat >> $FILENAME' so I can continuously enter commands. Works like a champ! Good call, Michiel!