# Put file contents on stdin without sending eof

Tags: bash

The typical way of putting a file's contents on stdin is as follows:

```
./command.sh < myfile
```

This puts all the contents of myfile on stdin and then sends the eof as well. I want to put the contents on stdin without adding the EOF.

For various interactive programs, I wish to begin the program with a sequence of commands, but then continue to interact with the program. If the eof is not sent, the program would wait for more input, which I could then type interactively.

Is this possible in bash? My current solution is to throw the contents on the clipboard and then just paste them. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: ( cat myfile;cat ) | sh command.sh

See, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561055/switch-from-file-contents-to-stdin-in-piped-command-linux-shell

Comment: An expect script using the *interact* command will be a more robust solution.

Answer (score 6):

Simply merge file with stdin by using `cat` command:

```
./command.sh < <(cat myfile -)
```

or

```
cat myfile - | ./command.sh
```

#### `cat` command

`cat` stand for *con**cat**enate*:

```
man cat
NAME
       cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

SYNOPSIS
       cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output.
...
```

(please **R**ead  **T**he **F**ine **M**anual ;-)

You could write

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ... fileN
```

as well as

```
cat file1 - file2

cat - file1

cat file1 -
```

depending on your need...

#### Complex sample, using *heredoc* and *herestring* instead of files

I use `head -c -1` in order to *drop* trailing *newline* in *heredoc*. `sed` command does simulate any command proccessing **line by line**:

```
sed 's/.*/[&]/' < <(cat <(head -c -1 <<eof 
Here is some text, followed by an empty line

Then a string, on THIS line: 
eof
) - <<<'Hello world')
```

Should output:

```
[Here is some text, followed by an empty line]
[]
[Then a string, on THIS line: Hello world]
```

Comment: ... where `-` stand for STDIN. (U could use: `cat myfile /dev/stdin | command...`)

Answer (score 2):

A solution for this is using a [fifo](/questions/tagged/fifo).

```
test -p /tmp/fifo || mkfifo /tmp/fifo

while true; do
    read line < /tmp/fifo
    echo "$line"
    [[ $line == break ]] && $line
done
```

and to feed the `fifo` :

```
echo foobar > /tmp/fifo
```

to stop "listening" :

```
echo break > /tmp/fifo
```

See `man mkfifo`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use another script to give your input:

### `inputer.sh`:

```
cat $1
while read line; do
  echo $line
done
```

### `Usage`:

```
sh inputer.sh input_file | sh your-script.sh
```