# C++ redirection file and also using keyboard input

Tags: c++, redirect, input

I want to read the file using redirection, but must also receive keyboard input. What should I do?

Comment: Rethink and read the file via a commandline parameter (file name) which you use to open an inputstream which then behaves like the input redirection. I write this in order to provoke you into explaining which advantages you want to harvest by using input redirection.

Comment: Only read the data you need from a file, and only put the stuff you need to the keyboard.

Comment: Why exactly do you feel you need this?

Comment: Do the answers from this similar linux question about piping a file and then switching stdin to keyboard help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561055/switch-from-file-contents-to-stdin-in-piped-command-linux-shell